# How to fix N/A Error with VLOOKUP in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to run a league that is being ranked and populated on a different sheet with the position in ascending order but some cells have the same score thereby giving out the same position and showing N/A in the other sheet

[image]

[image]

Comment: Google and this site are littered with information about how to handle this problem.  Please search around before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

Two causes:

1. The `lookup key` you're using is not in the table you're pulling from (or formatted differently, such a text vs. values).
2. There is an error that is being pulled from the table your pulling from (this case the formula is working properly, but it is pulling the error from the other sheet).

Comment: The second cause is the problem,so i need a way to show the values on the second sheet regardless of the fact they are both on the same positions

Comment: Okay so this isn't a `Vlookup` issue, its an issue on the other tab. Fix that and your vlookup will work fine. The positioning shouldn't matter since vlookup knows how to pull the information (unless there's duplicates)

Comment: Actually there are duplicates,the numbers are the same thereby making the same name on the same position and Vlookup is pulling just one result out of the same position

Comment: Duplicates won't pull an error, but it will pull the first instance of the duplicate value.

Comment: Exactly, I want it to pull out both instances, I don't want N/A coming up